# textbox enter causes postback or redirection?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, updatepanel

I've got a textbox and a button in asp.net wrapped in an updatepanel like so:

```
 <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel21" runat="server" UpdateMode="Always" >
             <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtLIDescription" runat="server" Columns="50">
                </asp:TextBox>
                 &nbsp;<asp:Button ID="btnAddLineItem" runat="server" onclick="btnAddLineItem_Click" 
                     Text="Add" ToolTip="Add line item." UseSubmitBehavior="false" />
                        </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

If I click the button everything works as expected.  But when I hit the enter key (which I think my users will do), the system seems to do a post back.  I tried to avoid it using jquery:

```
  $('#LineItemContent_txtLIDescription')
         .livequery('keyup', function (event) {
             if (event.keyCode == 13) {
                 $('#LineItemContent_btnAddLineItem').focus();
                 $('#LineItemContent_btnAddLineItem').click();
             }
             $("#LineItemContent_btnAddLineItem").button();
         });
```

If I place an `alert("hello world");` I see it has entered the if condition so it knows an enter has been clicked.  Then I was hoping to set the focus to the button and then have it click the button, just like a regular end user would click the button.  Nope seems to post back.

I tried adding:

```
event.preventDefault();
return false;
```

In the jquery hoping that will avoid it, nope same thing.  I even tried ASP.net markup and added

`UseSubmitBehavior=false`

And the page still seems to be posting back.  Is this due to it being inside an updatepanel?  Is there any other way around this??

Comment: Have you tried on 'keydown'? What happens when you hold down the enter button?

Comment: Travis - did you read my post...when I hit the enter key it does it goes into the if condition and set the focus and probably clicks but it does it so fast because it ends up posting back.

Comment: If your code was working properly then you would not enter that condition with the enter button pressed down. "The keyup event is sent to an element when the user releases a key on the keyboard." You are more than likely going to have to handle multiple events. But if you are content with just hacking a solution then just stick to not listening. Did you read my comment?

Comment: @TravisJ - my point was I was getting into the right place - i know how to debug I'm not a dummy, my issue was it still posted back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to wrap the content of the `UpdatePanel` in a  `Panel` and set it's [`DefaultButton`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.panel.defaultbutton.aspx) property to `btnAddLineItem`.

**Edit**: "The question is why does this work..."

First the cause of your issue: It's not ASP.NET specific that the first button in a form will be clicked when you press enter key, that's normal behaviour. But an UpdatePanel does an asynchronous postback only if the control that caused the postback is inside the UpdatePanel. Otherwise you need to specify an `AsyncPostBackTrigger` explicitely for that control.

My approach works since it ensures that the appropriate button (inside the UpdatePanel) is clicked when the user clicks enter inside that Panel. This causes an asynchronous postback as desired.

This is not a hack but a useful feature introduced in ASP.NET 2.0. Your code keeps being readable, you don't need to use "javascript hacks".

Comment: But the update panel is inside a div...could i reuse that somehow?

Comment: @oJM86o: A Panel will be rendered as a div. So you could replace your div with a panel.

Comment: @oJM86o: Edited my answer to add an explanation. Downvoter: Care to comment?